# LocalDb "No process on the end of the pipe"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've made a copy of my database (which is on Azure) on local SQLExpress server. On this server I have user "Tester" that has `db_owner` role for that database.

I can easily connect to it using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using server name: `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, SQL Server Authentication and "Tester" user credentials. but when I connect to it in my code with connection string like:

```
const string ConnectionString =
    "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
    "Initial Catalog=Integration-Tests;" +
    "Persist Security Info=False;" +
    "User ID=Tester;" +
    "Password=secretPassword;" +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=False;" +
    "Encrypt=True;" +
    "TrustServerCertificate=False;" +
    "Connection Timeout=30;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open(); // Exception thrown
        /* some more code that doesn't matter */
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I get following exception thrown:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Earlier I was getting something else, but I guess it could be a simple typo since it stopped happening, I'm including it just in case it helps:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

As stated earlier, everything works fine both on Azure, and I can connect to my LocalDb through SSMS.

Does anyone have any idea what could be cause of this error?

Comment: This is always a configuration error. It has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times. But the solution is not always the same thing. It requires knowledge of the settings on your DB which only you can access. Here is a great place to start. https://www.google.com/search?q=A+connection+was+successfully+established+with+the+server%2C+but+then+an+error+occurred+during+the+pre-login+handshake.+%28provider%3A+Named+Pipes+Provider%2C+error%3A+0+-+No+process+is+on+the+other+end+of+the+pipe.%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: I know it has been asked many times, but all cases I've checked didn't actually match my conditions, because either they were using Windows Authentication, or they couldn't connect with SSMS. On the other hand, I've found the answer, so I'll just post it in case someone has the same problem and it helps him.

Comment: Yeah it is a challenging error for sure because it can be caused by so many things. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer, posting it for anyone who ever has same problem:

I realized there was no verifiable server certificate, and according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax?view=netframework-4.7.2#enabling-encryption), with `Encrypt=true` in my connection string:

> Encryption occurs only if there is a verifiable server certificate, otherwise the connection attempt fails.

Indeed, the error code could be a little more descriptive... but all I had to do, was to remove `Encrypt` part from connection string.