# OleDbConnection wont connect to local database (mdf file) when using connection string provided by mdf file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

[image]

The first error I get insists a give a provider, I have tried multiple providers I've gotten through google searches. The second error when I specify a provider does not give details it just says No work done, check OLE DB status value.

[image]

The connection string provided by the `mdf` file is

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\...\AAS.mdf";Integrated Security=True".
```

I also tried using

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="AAS.mdf";Integrated Security=True"
```

and

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=AAS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

since the database is in the same file as the application.

Can someone let me know how to find the correct provider if that is the problem, or fix my connection string. (PS: this application will run on multiple computers possibly in different folders so preferably a solution not specifying the C drive)

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/ -- this is the page for SQL server compact on "connectionstrings.com" -- if this doesn't work there are details for other providers to try.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server, you don't want OleDBConnection, you want SqlConnection in System.Data.SqlClient namespace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: @GlennFerrie: a `.mdf` file is a regular SQL Server database file - **not** a SQL Server Compact one (that would have been `.sdf`)

Comment: If for some reason you absolutely need OleDb over the native Client, then here is OleDb connection strings for SQL Server: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: For OleDb, the bottom of this article has an OleDb connection that is supposed to work with LocalDB: https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/adodb-connection-string-for-localdb-and-sql-server-native-client/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename) I really wouldn't bother with this parameter at all, it probably doesn't do what you think it does, and any case you can't use it with the OleDB driver

Comment: @B.O.B. I've converted to System.Data.SqlClient now I'm getting "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe"

Comment: @DumisaniZitha Well I don't know about LocalDB, the full server has 3 different protocols that can be enabled or disabled, one of which is Named Pipes. The other two are Shared Memory and TCP/IP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298639/localdb-no-process-on-the-end-of-the-pipe see if that helps.